# I like to get IPTC's Title or Description character count

Tags: character, metadata, iptc, lightroom, adobe-bridge

I like to get IPTC's Title or Description character count and get files over 195 character count somehow marked
- In Adobe Bridge either sort, or label, or rate them (with a script or a plugin)
- In Lightroom somehow
- In any other tool with

E.g. moving the files to a directory would be sufficient

Renaming is not an option, duplicate and rename is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this on the command line/bash/terminal with [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org) and the following command.

`exiftool -if "${Description;$_=length()}>195" -Directory=/path/to/moved/ /path/to/source/`

To change the label on the those files, you would use
`exiftool -if "${Description;$_=length()}>195" -Label="Some Text" /path/to/source/`
Replace **Some Text** with what you want the label to say.

If used in terminal/bash, double/single quotes need to be swapped to avoid bash interpretation parts of the command as variables.

---

To get approximate word count as per original post:

`exiftool -if "${Description;$_=(()=/ +/g)+1}>195" -Directory=/path/to/moved/ /path/to/source/`

This command does a quick and dirty regex count of all the spaces between words in the `Description` and moves any files with a count greater than 195 to the `/path/to/moved/` directory.  It's not 100% perfect, for example it doesn't take into account things like dashes, i.e. `before—after` would be counted as one word.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, I need 195 character count. Good for start

Comment: That's even easier, updated post. You should correct your original question.  Additionally, instead of moving, you could set a tag such as `Label` and view the results in LR

Comment: How should I add the tag? That would be better. (Not to mess with original database of images)

Comment: I get this message:  
1 directories scanned
27 files failed condition
0 image files read ... I had run this code: exiftool -if "${Description;$_=(()=/ +/g)+1}>195" -Directory="F:\vektor 2019\200 char test\195 felett" "F:\vektor 2019\200 char test"

Comment: I'm using "IPTC core" to label, descriptions in Bridge

Comment: I double checked and has files over 195 chars

Comment: Make sure and use the correct command I listed above.  The first command is for number of characters.  Your comment used the command for number of words.

Comment: Yep. Worked. Thank you very much for the fast solution / answer! For others: note an "e" missing from "dirEctory"

Comment: Ooops, fixed it.